# iOS 8 / Custom TableViewCell / Template UIImage not showing up

Tags: ios, uiimage

I've got an image I want to display in my UITableViewCell / it's in the XCAssets and it's been set to render as a template always.

The image does not get tinted when I run it, and yet, if I select the row in the table view, the tint is applied!

Has anyone encountered this problem?

—

Similar: [Rendering mode set to Template for vector pdf in image catalogue, but UIImageView wont tint the image in a custom cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115346/rendering-mode-set-to-template-for-vector-pdf-in-image-catalogue-but-uiimagevie)

Comment: Show some code, please.

Comment: There is no code at this point. It's all in the storyboard / assets file(s).

Comment: thanks for linking my thread here. this problem has been bugging me too. and again, there is no code, everything is in xib/ asset catalogue. 
@IkoTikashi please follow the above link to my post. i have neat screen shots explaining what is wrong.